# Stuck on renaming all files with list provided by .txt file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with ~1000 files with very long names that I'm trying to change. I created a `rename.txt` file with the following general structure:

```
"/scratch1/WES/strelka/snvs/A35376_st_t_markdup.cram_A35377_st_g_markdup.cram_somatic.snvs.vcf,A35376_st_t_A35377_st_g_somatic.snvs.vcf"
```

So per the line above, I have the OLD name (with current directory and file name) separated by a comma with the desired new name of my file. I wrote this:

```
for f in 'cat rename.txt';
do
OLD=$(basename ${f} | cut -d, -f1);
NEW=$(basename ${f} | cut -d, -f2);
mv ${OLD} ${NEW}
done
```

I got this error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘cat’: No such file or directory
```

I had a ton of issues with this code before and finally got to this point, I'm not sure how to loop through each line of the file. I should note, I tried this (with the quote outside `rename.txt.` instead of including `cat`:

```
for f in cat 'rename.txt';
do
OLD=$(basename ${f} | cut -d, -f1);
NEW=$(basename ${f} | cut -d, -f2);
mv ${OLD} ${NEW}
done
```

And nothing is happening... I literally saw the '>' symbol and nothing is running. I'm very stuck, any advice would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you so much

EDIT: I fixed the quote type, my apologies for the error before.

Comment: Replace `'cat rename.txt'` with `$(cat rename.txt)` ... single quotes create a literal string, and back-ticks are bad practice.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. This worked, and I'm noting these tips/best practices as well. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome: next question - do you really mean to move the files to the current working directory or do you mean to rename them in place?

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: I meant to rename them in place, would there be a more efficient way to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Another, more efficient, option is a single call to `awk` to process the `rename.txt` file and move all the files using the `awk` `system()` command. The only thing that is unclear in your question is whether you want to move the filenames to another directory or leave the renamed file in the original directory.

Presuming you want to rename, leaving the renamed file in the original directory you can do:

```bash
awk -F, '{ dir=$1; sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",dir); dest= dir "/" $2; system("mv " $1 " " dest)  }' rename.txt
```

Above, the first field (the old filename) is saved in `dir` and the filename part is removed using the `sub()` command. The destination name `dest` is simply that directory with the new filename appended to the directory to allow renaming to the original directory.

The actual move command `mv` is executed in the `system()` command. The quotes provide spacing around the shell command.

The only caveat is if you can have spaces in either the directory or filename, you will need to add quotes using the octal or hex character notation, e.g.

```
system("mv \x27" $1 "\x27 \x27" dest "\x27")
```

The effect of which is `mv '$1' 'dest'` in a form that prevents word-splitting on either.

---

**Using bash**

You can use `IFS` (**I**neternal **F**ield **S**eperator) to split the contents of your `rename.txt` file on `','` and then move as was done above. Using the built-in *parameter expansion with substring removal* rather than `basename` and `cut` is much more efficient.

Every time you call a utility within a loop, you spawn an additional subshell (process). You should avoid that as it will kill the efficiency of your shell scripts. (not to mention calling `basename` and `cut` twice per-iteration) Bash parameter-expansions are built-ins and do not require a subshell.

Putting it altogether, your script could be written as:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-rename.txt}"              ## set input filename

## validate input file exists and is non-empty
[ -s "$fname" ] || {
  printf "error: input file doesn't exist or is empty.\n" >&2
  exit 1
}

## read each line in input file splitting on ',' with IFS
while IFS=$',\n' read -r old new; do
  dname="${old%/*}"                   ## strip name from old
  ## move old to new, reporting any error
  mv "$old" "$dname/$new" || {
    printf "error: mv to %s failed.\n" "$new" >&2
  }
done < "$fname"
```

If the script name was `do_rename.sh`, you would call the script with your `rename.txt` as its argument, e.g.

```
bash do_rename.sh rename.txt
```

Or, simply using the default if your input file is `rename.txt`

```
bash do_rename.sh
```

(or make the script executable with `chmod +x do_rename.sh` and then run as `./do_rename.sh rename.txt`, or `./do_rename.sh` with the default filename)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you SO much for this super helpful response. I actually tried this and also played with the "cut" options to format my names in a way that works for downstream analyses as well. In the past, I avoided using "awk" because I found it confusing but in this context, I understand it more and will try to enhance some of my scripts from now on. Thanks again, David!! I appreciate your help/thorough answer to this.

Comment: Glad to help. `awk` is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. It can't be beat. I used to be intimidated by it as well. Then it just snapped. It's basically C like that uses REGEX of strings for conditional matching. Well worth taking the time to learn [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)